doPost not getting called when fetch executed but works for HTTP client call
I am trying to execute a simple apps script function deployed as web app. This web app has a single function doPost with a simple console print statement. When I try to execute this script from JS client using fetch method, I am getting error "Script function not found: doGet".
However when I execute this from a HTTP client tool like Bruno I am able to execute the web app and the results are as expected.
How to resolve this issue?
Apps script code
function doPost(e) {

  console.log('Posted data from client is..',JSON.stringify(e))
}

Client side JS code
const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/myscriptid/exec";

let appbody = {
                  "fruit_name" : "Orange",
                  "qty" : "210"
              }

let optionsin = {      
                  "headers" : {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
                            },
                  "method": "POST",
                  "body": JSON.stringify(appbody)
              }

function samplefunc()

  {
       try 
        {
               console.log("About to call fetch")
                   fetch(url, {optionsin})
                .then(response => {return response.json()} )
                .then(result => {console.log(' result from  api call', result);
                         })  
                 } 
       catch (error) 
                 {
                    console.log('Error in triggering fetch', error.message)
                 }
  }
samplefunc();


How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?

Modification points:

From your showing Javascript, I suppose that your Web Apps is deployed as Execute as: Me and Who has access to the app: Anyone. If your actual setting is different from this, the below script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

In the case of your showing doPost, no value is returned. And, I'm worried that even when doPost is run with the event object e, the log might not be shown in the log. But, if your Google Apps Script project has already been linked with the Google Cloud Platform project, the log can be seen. Ref (Author: me)

In your Javascript, { optionsin } of fetch(url, { optionsin }) is the same with { optionsin: optionsin }. In this case, the values in optionsin is not used. I guessed that this might be the reason for your current issue of Script function not found: doGet.
When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?


Modified script:
Google Apps Script side:
function doPost(e) {
  console.log('Posted data from client is..', JSON.stringify(e))
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e));
}

Javascript side:
Please set your Web Apps URL to url.
const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/myscriptid/exec";

let appbody = {
  "fruit_name": "Orange",
  "qty": "210"
};
let optionsin = {
  "method": "POST",
  "body": JSON.stringify(appbody)
};

function samplefunc() {
  try {
    console.log("About to call fetch");
    fetch(url, { ...optionsin }) // or fetch(url, optionsin)
      .then(response => { return response.json() })
      .then(result => {
        console.log(' result from  api call', result);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error in triggering fetch', error.message);
  }
}

samplefunc();

Testing:
When this Javascript is run, the following value is given as the event object e. Also, this value is also returned to Javascript by return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e)). You can see it in the console.
{
  "postData": { "contents": "{\"fruit_name\":\"Orange\",\"qty\":\"210\"}", "length": 35, "name": "postData", "type": "text/plain" },
  "parameters": {},
  "parameter": {},
  "contentLength": 35,
  "contextPath": "",
  "queryString": ""
}

Note:

When you modify the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.

You can see the details of this in my report "Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)".


References:

Web Apps
Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script (Author: me)

